# Optical Flow implementation in Objective C with Xcode

Tags: objective-c

Does anyone have or know of an implementation of optical flow in Objective C? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV has an implementation of optical flow. It's not Objective-C per se, but it is C.

The PDF in the second link has a complete example of using optical flow.

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/

http://robots.stanford.edu/cs223b05/notes/CS%20223-B%20T1%20stavens_opencv_optical_flow.pdf

Answer (score 0):

opencv has a framework for iOS(can be downloaded from http://opencv.org/), and you can directly use opencv's optical flow calculation function cv::calcOpticalFlowPyrLK
(dense optical flow algorithm is also available in opencv)

Answer (score -1):

There is a C++ implementation in Matlab.
http://people.csail.mit.edu/celiu/OpticalFlow/